# Get coming day from any given date with Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

How can i get the next Sunday from the given date with `Carbon`,Like i want to get he next Sunday from this date.

2017-04-03 which would be **2017-04-09**,

I can get coming Sunday from  `new Carbon('next sunday');` ,but i need to get it from specific date.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this:

```
Carbon::parse($someDate)->endOfWeek()
```

You can also chain `->startOfDay()` if time part is important.

Or you can do this:

```
Cabon::parse($someDate)->startOfWeek()->addDays(6)
```

Comment: It also returning me the past date.Suppose i have this date "2017-03-29",then this is returning 2017-03-28,how can i get only coming dates.thanks

Comment: @WaqasAli I've just tested this and got `2017-04-02`. Maybe the problem is in timezone you use in your app or something?